# reset default application to open with a file ( .crt)

Tags: 14.04, file-association, file-type

using **Ubuntu 14.04**

I have 1 files `.crt` extension. when I click to open , it open with **view file** application which displays the certificate information and other details which is fine.

Now I have changed the deafult application from context menu option **Open With Other Application** and set it to gedit and now can see the file content.

Now I want to reset the default open with the app by *View file*  but there is no such entry in the list of *Other Applications*.

the property of the file is `X.509 Certificate (application/pkix-cert)`

Trial 1:

check `cat /usr/share/applications/defaults.list` but there is no entry for this type ofapplication/extension here

Trial 2:

Tried with *ubuntu-tweak* tool but there is no option to select *view file* application for this type of application.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps

```
sudo edit ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

there is the entry

```
[Added Associations]  
application/x-x509-ca-cert=gedit.desktop;  
application/pkcs7-signature=gedit.desktop;  
application/pkix-cert=gedit.desktop;  
application/x-pem-key=gedit.desktop;
```

remove above  entry and also  remove from `[Default Associations]` section and update the file.

`nautilus -q` can be executed after this if it doesn't affect quickly.

Answer (score 4):

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.
Right click the file → Select Property → Open With → Reset

[image: Reset]

Comment: Works in debian 9.6 too

Answer (score 2):

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and for me the location of `[Added Associations]` was at

```
~/.config/mimeapps.list
```

Before editing it is good practice to backup the original file and then edit. I used the commands as follows:

```
cp ~/.config/mimeapps.list{,_old}
vim ~/.config/mimeapps.list
```

Remove the certificate file related entries. For myself I had to remove

```
[Added Associations]
application/x-pkcs12=org.gnome.gedit.desktop;
application/x-x509-ca-cert=kse.desktop;apturl.desktop;org.gnome.gedit.desktop;
application/pkix-cert=org.gnome.gedit.desktop;nautilus-autorun-software.desktop;
```

Then you can delete the old file if you want.

Answer (score 1):

The default applicaiont is 'gcr-viewer'.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to AU! This would be more appropriate as a comment on the original question, as it doesn't provide a full answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the name of the application.